# Не получается назначить права на файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Не получается назначить права на файл. Прошу помощи!!!:

```
FileInfo ^ info3 = gcnew FileInfo("D:\\CountIn.txt");
FileSecurity^ fSec = info3->GetAccessControl();
GetLastError();
fSec->AddAccessRule(gcnew FileSystemAccessRule("\\Admin-PC\User", 
FileSystemRights::ReadData, AccessControlType::Allow));
info3->SetAccessControl("D:\\CountIn.txt", fSec);
```

GetLastError() возвращает ошибку 122:

> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER Область данных, переданная системному
>   вызову, слишком мала.

И в итоге не работает ничего. Права не назначены... Что это значит? Что необходимо сделать? Как? Помогите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверять результат GetLastError из-под .NET бессмысленно, если вы сами не вызываете функции из WinAPI. Какая именно функция и почему установила этот код ошибки, сказать невозможно.

Ошибка же в вашем коде в том, что неправильно задано имя пользователя. Оно задается в формате `DOMAIN\\account` (где DOMAIN может быть и именем компьютера, для локальных учетных записей). Символы `\\` в начале лишние, но второй символ `\` при записи строковой константы в С++ должен быть повторен два раза. Вот итоговый рабочий код:

```
FileInfo ^ info3 = gcnew FileInfo("D:\\CountIn.txt");
FileSecurity^ fSec = info3->GetAccessControl();

fSec->AddAccessRule(gcnew FileSystemAccessRule("Admin-PC\\User", 
     FileSystemRights::ReadData, AccessControlType::Allow));
info3->SetAccessControl(fSec);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, убрав символы \\, права не были изменены... В чем может быть проблемы? Что мне еще стоит попробовать? Прошу, подскажите!

Comment: @Anna обновил ответ

Comment: СПАСИБО НЕВЕРОЯТНОЕ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!